# How to set properties referenced from dependencies in Maven

Tags: maven, properties, dependency-management

In my project I've got maven dependency.
by the way it's:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
   <artifactId>mule-module-activiti</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In this dependency POM there is a property that is used but not defined - `${activiti.version}`

The only way I found how to set this property is by specifying it on the command line like `mvn -Dactiviti.version=5.10`

Is there some way how to specify this property in my project's POM?
`<properties><activiti.version>5.10</activiti.version></properties>` doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

Situation I'm trying to solve can be reproduced if you create new maven project with dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
   <artifactId>mule-module-activiti</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and provide required repositories:

```
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>muleforge-repo</id>
            <name>MuleForge Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.muleforge.org/release</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>codehaus-repo</id>
            <name>Codehaus Repository</name>
            <url>http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>activiti</id>
            <name>Activiti</name>
            <url>https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a [POM](http://repository.muleforge.org/release/org/mule/modules/mule-module-activiti/3.2.0/mule-module-activiti-3.2.0.pom) for **org.mule.modules:mule-module-activiti:3.2.0**, library my projects depends on. Inside of this pom they use expression `${activiti.version}`. But they **don't** set value for this expression.  (there is nothing like `<properties><activiti.version>5.10</activiti.version></properties>`)

The question is how can I set a value for this expression from **my** pom?

Comment: Using the properties section of a pom is the best solution. Why does it not working for u?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, finally, after a few days of searching and experimenting I found a solution for my problem.

If you need to provide properties for maven on the command line (talking about **system properties**, which are slightly different from **maven properties**), you can also use a plugin to provide these properties in your pom or in the separate properties file.

**note:**
System properties can be used for overriding maven properties in your dependencies.

Like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>activiti.version</name>
                        <value>5.10</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I hope it will be of some help to someone.

Also sorry for my clumsy question which was apparently hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I had a similar issue and didn't know how to frame my issue but i was in great luck that i found your post!

Answer (score 4):

You can use properties to define versions:

```
<properties>
  <module-version>3.2.0</module-version>
</properties>
..
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
   <artifactId>mule-module-activiti</artifactId>
   <version>${module-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Why shouldn't [that work](https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp/blob/master/pom.xml)?

You should never define versions of artifacts via properties on command line, cause you can't reproduce this in the future and i doubt that this works.

Comment: Yes what you described definitely works. What I tried to talk about was the case when dependency I use define version of IT's dependency with property, but doesn't specify it's value.
Check this pom - http://repository.muleforge.org/release/org/mule/modules/mule-module-activiti/3.2.0/mule-module-activiti-3.2.0.pom

Comment: Shouldn't the dependencies for integration tests the same as for unit tests and for creation of release artifact.

Comment: Yes, probably, but I don't own this dependency and I need to use it. I'm trying to avoid having to provide parameters on command line everytime I need to build my project.

Comment: Of course not, but why not simply giving the version number into your pom? Furthermore you shouldn't define repositories in your pom you should use a repository manager instaed.

Comment: I don't own this POM: http://repository.muleforge.org/release/org/mule/modules/mule-module-activiti/3.2.0/mule-module-activiti-3.2.0.pom, I can't change it, I can't put version number in there. I have to provide it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a proxy settings for talking to outside world. I just tried your configuration and it worked. I am using latest Maven 3 release.

Comment: Did you set command line parameter? Something like: 
'mvn clean install -Dactiviti.version=5.10', or You run it without parameter like - 'mvn clean install'?

Comment: I provided properties like <properties>
  <module-version>3.2.0</module-version>
</properties> in pom.xml. you can also try to do it from command line and it shud still work

Comment: I tried to elaborate more on my question (EDIT 2). If I don't specify parameter '-Dactiviti.version=5.10' I'm getting: 'error: error reading C:\Programs\maven\repository\org\activiti\activiti-engine\${activiti.version}\activiti-engine-${activiti.version}.jar; error in opening zip file'